# Core data termination error

Tags: ios, swift, class, core-data

I have an app which saves user input, implemented by Core data. When building my project, I get a **Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT**, and the following error message:

> 2016-03-06 09:34:47.893 On The Go[59689:24714046] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '"On_The_Go.Agenda" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'

Here is my `Agenda.swift` class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Agenda {

@NSManaged var subject:String
@NSManaged var deadline:String
@NSManaged var urgent:NSNumber?
}
```

Here is my `MainTableViewController.swift`, which acts as my initial view controller, where the user inputted data appears (I have only shown the code involving this error to prevent too much code):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var content:[Agenda] = []
var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Agenda")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "subject", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            content = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [Agenda]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }

        case .Delete:
            if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }

        case .Update:
            if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }

        default:
            tableView.reloadData()
    }

    content = controller.fetchedObjects as! [Agenda]
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

}
```

Here is the `AddItemController.swift`, where the user adds their information:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddItemController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var subjectTextField:UITextField!
@IBOutlet var deadlineTextField:UITextField!
@IBOutlet var yesButton:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var noButton:UIButton!

var urgent = true
var content:Agenda!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func save(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {

    let subject = subjectTextField.text
    let deadline = deadlineTextField.text

    if subject == "" || deadline == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Not all of the fields have been filled in. Please fill them in before proceeding.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

        content = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Agenda", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Agenda
        content.subject = subject!
        content.deadline = deadline!
        content.urgent = urgent

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func toggleUrgentButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender == yesButton {
        urgent = true
        yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        noButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    } else if sender == noButton {
        urgent = false
        yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        noButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
}
```

FYI, on the line `content = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Agenda", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Agenda`, I get the warning:

> Cast from 'NSManagedObject' to unrelated type 'Agenda' always fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself, I changed

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Agenda {

@NSManaged var subject:String
@NSManaged var deadline:String
@NSManaged var urgent:NSNumber?
}
```

To

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Agenda:NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var subject:String
@NSManaged var deadline:String
@NSManaged var urgent:NSNumber?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared class Agenda extending NSManagedObject. Your Agenda.swift file should look like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc (Agenda)
class Agenda : NSManagedObject{

    @NSManaged var subject:String
    @NSManaged var deadline:String
    @NSManaged var urgent:NSNumber?
}
```